# Can't seem to increase java heap size on intellij in windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I have an Android Flex/AIR application I'm developing in Intellij 2017. When I try to debug it on my phone I keep getting the out of memory error.

```
dx tool failed:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.BitSet.initWords(BitSet.java:166)
    at java.util.BitSet.<init>(BitSet.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.<init>(SsaBasicBlock.java:128)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:147)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:173)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:103)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:44)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:297)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:734)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:678)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:607)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:637)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:511)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:281)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

It shows me the command being used:

```
DT command line: D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\jre64\bin\java.exe .... ... -Xmx512m -jar ... ...
```

Erased most, but it shows that it's using 512m for the memory. I have gone into the compiler settings and set the "Build process heap size" option to 2056 but that hasn't helped. I've also added the JAVA_OPTS variable with a value of "-Xms128 -Xmx2056m"

I'm not sure what where Intellij is getting that setting to change it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the original command that gets run, and no matter what I've tried so var it always says -Xmx512m

```
D:\<path_to_intellij>\java.exe -Dapplication.home=D:\<path_to_flex_sdk> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=en -Xmx512m -jar D:\<path_to_flex_sdk>\lib\adt.jar -package -target apk-debug -listen 7936 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore D:\<path_to_key_file> -storepass <password> D:\<output_path>\GROL.apk
```

**EDIT 2**

If I take the command given from the Intellij IDEA and run it manually on the command line and change the 512 to something higher it works. There just seems to be no setting in IntelliJ for this particular action. I'll have to post on the IntelliJ forums and maybe get some dev help over there. If they respond, I'll answer it on here

Comment: My guess is that Idea itself needs more memory, can you try the steps described in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/increasing-memory-heap.html) and see if they work for you?

Comment: I have tried to edit a custom vmoptions file and that also does not work. The default file in the installation folder shows -Xmx750m and -Xms128m. So not the 512 that is in the command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it here (Actionscript & Flex Compiler heap size):

[image: flex heap]

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I don't think that will work as the compilation of the SWF works just fine, it's the packaging into an APK that fails

Comment: @kamcknig depending on your Flex SDK version, [the following](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd9.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5fb32-7ff3) may work (`SDK/bin/jvm.config`, `java.args=-Xmx1024m`).

Comment: That will change it for the mxmlc compiler, but not the adt packager

Comment: @kamcknig I've checked through [the source code](http://i.imgur.com/uYxu8ze.png) and it appears that IntelliJ IDEA is using the heap setting from the screenshot shown in the answer when running adt packaging tool. Please confirm. It reads the value from `jvm.config`, gets the value from the Flex Compiler configuration UI and uses the one which is higher. Try setting the `Compiler heap size` value to `1024m`, restart IntelliJ IDEA and see if it changes the command line.

Comment: Ah! You are indeed correct! Sorry I doubted you, thank you for taking the time to actually dig into that!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this settings from IntelliJ menu bar, go to `Help > Edit Custom VM Options...`, this will create a copy of your existing `/bin/idea.exe.vmoptions` or `/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions` file from the installation folder and it will open to edit.

You can use `-Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>`, for example, the final file should look like:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms750m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

For the changes to take effect it is necessary to restart IntelliJ

Another alternative is settings the size in the `Run/Debug configurations` option, for to do that go to menu bar `Run > Edit Configurations...`, and add `-Xms750m -Xmx2048m` in `VM Options` field

Comment: This doesn't affect compiler settings.

Comment: The vmoptions is how much memory Intellij uses, not the build process, though I have edited that file and the output of the error and command line still shows "-Xmx 512m". For the run/debug configuration; that is for the compiler but this is a flex/air project which is compiled with mxmlc and that doesn't need as much memory, that works. It fails on using the adt packaging tool